# WebService returning illegible text using volley StringRequest

Tags: android, json, web-services, request, encode

I'm trying to get some data out of a webservice, using Volley StringRequst, but I'm getting illegible text and I can't seem to encode it the right way.

[Link for webservice](http://www.cupomapps.com.br/coupon_service.asmx/Country?lang_id=1) so you can see that it does return the JSON data properly on browser.

**My url string:**

```
<string name="url_country">http://www.cupomapps.com.br/coupon_service.asmx/Country?lang_id=%1$s</string>
```

**StringRequest:**

```
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            String.format(getString(R.string.url_country),"1"),
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    String s1="";
                    try {
                        s1 = new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "JSON String s response: " + s);
                    Log.i(TAG, "JSON String s1 response: " + s1);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error String JSON: "+ volleyError.getMessage());
                }
            }
    );
    RequestManager.getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
```

**What I'm getting on first log:**

> 03-26 16:36:36.645  12699-12699/com.direito.coupons I/MainActivity﹕ JSON String s response: eο
>       �0�W)7w0�AȦ��\��HH�1P[�$C)}1W_�+L�v����c�����]�� G(�G������"�j64��'㋆�a�8l
>   ���B����_�z*h����b�GNd��L��mSv&�]��B�ӵ��CJ.�q�)�O�U��Q���V��΍H͍��TO_

**What I'm getting on second log:**

> 03-26 16:36:36.645  12699-12699/com.direito.coupons I/MainActivity﹕ JSON String s1 response: e?
>       ?0?W)7w0?A???\??HH?1P[?$C)}1W_?+L?v????c?????]�� G(?G??????"?j64??'??a?8l
>   ???B????_?z*h????b?GNd??L??mSv&?]??B????CJ.?q?)?O?U??Q???V???H???TO_

So I don't know if I'm encoding it the right way, I'm able to perform StringRequests with other webservices and get the JSON string without any problems.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the same type of issue?

Comment: Sorry, I stopped trying to solve this issue because the project died.
But, you should probably try to encode on some other base or charset, or check if  the logger is the real problem and is not showing you the right result (altought I don't think so). Good luck, I can only say that I lost a lot of time trying to solve this issue, it would be a lot easier to just build a working WebService.

Comment: I don't know what was the issue, but eventually I used apache httpclient and the error was gone. I tried volley and then urlconnection both of them had the same issue until I used apache httpclient.

Comment: Oh good to know, if this happens in the future I'll try that.